# Tense in a reported speech

Tags: tense

I saw the following in CNN news:

> Announcing details of the itinerary on Friday, the UK government disclosed that Trump will attend a black-tie dinner hosted by Prime Minister Theresa May at Blenheim Palace, the birthplace of the UK's celebrated wartime leader.

Is it grammatically incorrect to say Trump "will" attend? Shouldn't we use Trump "would" attend, since "disclosed" is a past tense? Is there any difference between these two usages?

Comment: He hasn't attended the dinner yet, so it's still in the future.

Comment: Both are fine. As are "should," "might," and "could." All of those words can be used with respect to something in the future. (Which you use is a matter of exactly what you're trying to express and personal choice.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not grammatically incorrect.

Because Trump has not yet attended the event, any disclosure prior that the event should use the **past** + **future tense**. *A news report on a developing story would use this combination.*

You are right that it is possible to use "would attend." However, that usage of the **past** + **past conditional** would only be appropriate after both the disclosure and the event occured. *A history book about the Trump presidency would use this combination.*

The difference between the two usages you've identified results from **whether just one event has occured or whether both have occured**.

Comment: Here's a usage example for 'to disclose' (= to make public or known) from Merriam-Webster: _The company has **disclosed that it will** be laying off thousands of workers later this year._ https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclose  Looks like there's a difference between 'said' and 'disclosed [a piece of information, a fact]'. What do you think about it?